# Why am getting Bad Request in login page and search form, FLASK?

Tags: python, apache, flask

If i want to log into my control panel am getting 400 bad request error that says:

**Bad Request**

`The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.`

I have also a search form , if i want to search for something through the database, am getting the same error .

The site is working on `Apache` webserver, what really interesting is that, if a ran the application using the `python manage.py runserver` command, the error won't show any more just in Apache the error showing up .

Here is how the code looks like in my **views.py**:

```
@app.route('/login/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))

@auth.login_required

def login():



    if session.get('username') or session.get('is_author') == True:

            flash("Already logged in .")

            return redirect(url_for('index'))



    form = LoginForm()

    error = None



    if request.method == 'GET' and request.args.get('next'):

        session['next'] = request.args.get('next')



    if form.validate_on_submit():

        user = User.query.filter_by(

            username = form.username.data

        ).first()



        if user:

            if bcrypt.hashpw(form.password.data, user.password) == user.password:

                session['username'] = form.username.data

                session['is_author'] = user.is_author



                if 'next' in session:

                    next = session.get('next')

                    session.pop('next')

                    return redirect(next)

                else:

                    flash('Welcome back %s'%session['username'].upper())

                    return redirect(url_for('index'))



            else:

                error = "Incorrect username or password ."

                flash(error)

        else:

            flash(error)

            error = "Incorrect username or username ."



    return render_template('auth/login.html', form=form)
```

Also the search code in **views.py**:

```
def replace_last(source_string, replace_what, replace_with):

    head, sep, tail = source_string.rpartition(replace_what)

    return head + replace_with + tail



@app.route('/search/<query>', methods=['GET','POST'])

def search_engine(query):



    user = User.query.first()



    try:

        query = request.form['autocomplete']

        r = replace_last(query, ' ', '')

        posts = Post.query.filter(Post.title.like('%'+r+'%')).order_by(Post.publish_date.desc())



    except TypeError:

        flash('No results.')

        return render_template('main/search_form.html')



    context = {

            "posts":posts,

            "r":r,

            "user":user,

            "query":query

    }



    return render_template('main/search_form.html', **context)
```

Another thing to mention is that, my site is running under **HTTPS** , maybe this causing some problems, i really don't know !! , in fact am using Letsencrypt, in another article I've seen the people are saying that there's a certain problem when using flask and HTTPS especially when using requests like POST or GET, but i really deleted Letsencrypt from my server restarted Apache but that didn't solved the problem , am really frustrated don't know what to do.

Another thing i forgot to add, is the App.conf in /etc/apache2/site-available , maybe it help some way to know what causing the problem :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
                ServerName site.com
                ServerAlias www.site.com
                WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/MyApp/flaskapp.wsgi
                <Directory /var/www/MyApp/siteapp/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                Alias /static /var/www/MyApp/siteapp/static
                <Directory /var/www/MyApp/siteapp/static/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                LogLevel warn
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.site.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =site.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Inside `sites-available/App.conf` i did a proxy redirection, so i ran my application using the `runserver` command, then inside App.conf i added these too lines of codes :

```
    ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:5000/
```

So by that, the **Bad Request** disappeared, the wired thing now is, always i'am getting **wtform** error that says:

`This field is required.`

means its empty, practically its not, i really typing information and handling them inside my **views.py** as i mentioned above .

Eventually, please any help would be a millions appreciated .

Comment: I can't really do any request any more even subscribe, always showing up **Bad Request**, please any possible help !

Comment: Any help please !

Comment: Also i can't add any comments, its showing up Bad Request always .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, in case you faced this unbelievable, undebugable problem do the following:

1. remove `Apache2` with all it dependencies, so :

   `sudo apt-get purge apache2 apache2-utils`
2. then follow this tutorial which is about, how to deploy your flask
   application on `nginx webserver`:

   https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04

That's it, I'am really truly very happy right now :) .